# Forecast horizon and small sample problem

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, prediction

I have a stationary time series with slight persistence, if any; like stock returns. They are collected in weekly frequency, $N$ obs. I try to predict them with an $AR(1)$ model. The well known prediction function is

$E[y_{t+1}|I_t]=\theta y_t$

However I’am interested in three month time horizon forecasting too ($12$ weeks). Unfortunately I do not have a very long time series and $N/12$ obs are too few for achieving a good precision; with more complex models things go worse yet. Now it seems me that I can proceeds as follow.

With my $AR(1)$ model I can predict $h$ step ahead in this way

$E[y_{t+h}|I_t]=\theta^h y_t$

However I’m not interested in predict $y_{t+h}$ but $x_{t+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{h} y_{t+i}$

So I can make several forecast from $1$ to $h$ and sum them. So I have my prediction, say
$\hat x_{t+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{h} \hat y_{t+i}$.

Finally I can compare $x_{t+1}$ and $\hat x_{t+1}$.

I’m not sure that this procedure is correct. It is? There is a better one? I can extend this at more general models?

I ask also because I noted that in some place predictions like $E[y_{t+h}|I_t]=\theta^h y_ t$ are used in unclear way. More precisely, with example $h=12$, this prediction made today (time $t$) would be for the 12-th week ahead. It is not for a quarter from $t+1$ to $t+12$; for that we must use $\hat x_{t+1}$. Or at least I think so.

Comment: Your logic makes sense to me.